# Loosing grid lines and ticks upon reciprocal transform in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, transform

ever since I last updated R I seem to loose grid lines and ticks when applying a reciprocal transform.

```
library(ggplot2)

sp  <-  ggplot  (cars, 
                aes (x = speed, 
                    y = dist)
                ) + 
                geom_point() +
                scale_x_continuous  (name = "Speed of cars", 
                                    limits = c(0, 30)
                                    ) +
                scale_y_continuous  (name = "Stopping distance", 
                                    trans = 'reciprocal'
                                    )

png('test.png')
print(sp)
dev.off()
```

Specifying breaks does not fix the problem. Other transforms work fine. I'm pretty sure this used to work fine with a previous version of ggplot2, although I cannot tell which version exactly that was.

This is my current seesionInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_1.0.4      withr_2.5.0      dplyr_1.1.0      utf8_1.2.3      
 [5] grid_4.2.2       R6_2.5.1         lifecycle_1.0.3  gtable_0.3.1    
 [9] magrittr_2.0.3   scales_1.2.1     pillar_1.8.1     rlang_1.0.6     
[13] cli_3.6.0        generics_0.1.3   vctrs_0.5.2      glue_1.6.2      
[17] munsell_0.5.0    compiler_4.2.2   pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_2.1-0
[21] tidyselect_1.2.0 tibble_3.2.0
```

Can someone reproduce this? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there a fix?

Many thanks in advance,

mce1

[image]

Comment: I get the same issue. I'm on R 4.3.0 and ggplot2 3.4.2 on Windows 11. Might be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: Bug report submitted! https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5310

Comment: Does the dev version of ggplot2 solve the problem? See e.g. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5271

Comment: @teunbrand Yes - that's the same issue. I missed that one!

Comment: @mce1 Until the next release of `ggplot2`, one fix would be to plot `y = 1 / dist` and set some suitable `breaks` and `labels` parameters in the `scale_y_continuous` statement (without the `transform`).